# Allied Mission 5 - Rescue Tanya

Tags: command-and-conquer-red-alert

I've on Allied mission 5 in Red Alert, where Tanya has been captured by the Soviets and I am sent in with one spy to rescue her. The Soviet base is full of soldiers that I have no problems in killing, but the dogs keep hunting me down and failing the mission for me.

What is the best method of rescuing Tanya, and completing this mission?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoid the dogs. Use barrels whenever possible to take out large groups of soldiers\dogs. Often in these sort of missions also, there is usually some form of POW section for you to recruit reinforcements. Take the time to kill\blow up everything you can safely manage to and see what happens.

Wow. You have nothing but a single spy. I forgot this was the mission you were mentioning because it's early and I'm tired. I apologize, in this mission your best bet is patience. Many of the patrols have different paths if you wait long enough to see them, allowing you time to pass. The part about finding POW's still applies, only you cant blow anything up so only your presence would be required to free the prisoners. I can't remember the exact specifics of this mission as it has been too long but that should be the gist.

Comment: It's also worth evacuating Tanya the moment the chinook turns up, since even after this point if she dies you will still fail the mission